# How to pass data frame object from renderUI to eventReactive?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I hope I am clear. I want to know how to pass user input data frame from renderUI to evenReactive in the server function. The problem is that in the eventReactive, ct is not found. Please advise !

My code is as follow:

```
ui <-
  fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Import",
                accept = c(".xlsx")),
      uiOutput("selectCAT"),
      actionButton("goBu", "Click!")),

    mainPanel("Display Results"
              tableOutput("acBTTON")
    ))



server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  output$selectCAT <- renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    ct <- read_excel(input$file1$datapath, sheet = "abc")
    empl <- read_excel(input$file2$datapath, sheet = "emp")

    selectInput(inputId = "showp",
                label = "Selection",
                empl)})
}


 pf <- eventReactive(input$goBu,{
    s1 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM ct")
  })
  output$acBTTON <- renderTable({
    pf()})
```

Comment: How/why are you passing a `data.frame` to `selectInput`? I'd expect a column from the frame perhaps, or a subset, but not the whole frame. Also, why do you use `renderUI`? I'm used to using it when I have a variable number (even 0) of shiny objects. In this case, I'd think you could start with the static input, then `updateSelectInput` once you set the file and find the candidate choices.

Comment: Objects created within a `render` or `reactive` block are disposed of unless they are specifically returned from the block. It is possible to force side-effect and store them elsewhere, but I highly discourage this thinking, as it breaks much of shiny's value and is a real bugger to debug when (not if) things don't flow like you want.

Comment: Are your `xlsx?` files always structure perfectly? You might want some safety logic in there, such as `if (!"emp" %in% colnames(...)) ...`. Never trust the user.

Comment: **How/why are you passing a data.frame to selectInput? I'd expect a column from the frame perhaps, or a subset, but not the whole frame. Also, why do you use renderUI ? **   @r2evans  I wasn't passing the data frame to selectInput. I was just putting it there so that when we ran the app the browse button appears and the person can select a file and it will read those sheets into a data frame. Can you give me some examples of static input and then updateSelectInput ?  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Are your xlsx? files always structure perfectly? You might want some safety logic in there, such as if (!"emp" %in% colnames(...)) .... Never trust the user.   @ r2evans, good advise, I am going to look into this and will apply it.

Comment: I just want to be able to call ct or other data frames in eventReactive from when the user input the file in renderUI that creates data frames. If I put  `req(input$file1)
    ct <- read_excel(input$file1$datapath, sheet = "abc")` in Global R user can select the file but the data frames are not created.

Comment: `empl <- read_excel(...);...;selectInput(inputId, label, empl)` tells me that you are passing a frame. The `read_excel` function says that it returns a `tibble` (which is a frame, reclassed), so I'm not sure what else could happen. For help with `updateSelectInput`, I suggest starting with [`?updateSelectInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateSelectInput.html) that has a built-in example.

Comment: @r2evans - my goal is to move the data frame, empl and ct to eventReactive. Can this be done ? My code above, only shows the data frame in UI, not eventReactive where I can possibly do other things with the data frame.

Comment: @r2evans - sorry if I am confusing you. But you are correct. Empl or whatever is in the there in the selectInput should be a column only. So let’s say I create empl2 <- sqldf (“select col from empl group by col”) in renderUI and put empl2 in the selectInput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things about this verbose/augmented sample app.

- I don't think you really need `uiOutput` and `renderUI`, since what you are trying to do is change the available options in a `selectInput`.
- I included some verbosity, so you can (for example) see `req` working, easily disabled or removed (I often have this code in my own shiny apps, disabled by default, for when I need to troubleshoot anything that might involve reactivity). (If you see `In:` and no corresponding `Out:`, this means the `req` line interrupted flow due to insufficient requirements.)
- You referenced `file2` in your example but never set it up ... I ignored it, but I think you could extend your `ui` to accommodate it, and `server` logic to handle it.
- The use of `sqldf` is generally safe enough, but the SQL it suggests does not guard (directly) against SQL injection. If you take these queries with user-defined free text, more safeguards should be taken.
- I added `defcat`, a "select a category" type message in the pull-down. Because it's obviously not something you want to filter on, I explicitly ensure it is not the selected category before filtering (and therefore rendering).

Given that, I'll present two results: one without `renderUI`, and one with it.

---

The first, without:

```
library(shiny)
library(sqldf)

defcat <- "Select a category ..."
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file1", "Import", accept = ".xlsx"),
    selectInput("selectCAT", "Category", choices = defcat),
    actionButton("goBu", "Click!")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    "Display Results",
    tableOutput("acBTTON")
  )
)

verbose <- TRUE
msg <- if (verbose) message else c

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat_mt <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    msg("In: dat_mt ...")
    req(input$file1)
    out <- readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath, "mt")
    msg("Out: dat_mt ...")
    out
  })
  dat_ir <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    msg("In: dat_ir ...")
    req(input$file1)
    out <- readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath, "ir")
    msg("Out: dat_ir ...")
    out
  })

  observeEvent(dat_mt(), {
    msg("In: observe dat_mt() ...")
    req(dat_mt())
    sel <- if (input$selectCAT %in% dat_mt()$cyl) input$selectCAT else defcat
    updateSelectInput(session, "selectCAT",
                      choices = c(defcat, sort(unique(dat_mt()$cyl))),
                      selected = sel)
    msg("Out: observe dat_mt() ...")
  })

  pf <- eventReactive(input$goBu, {
    msg("In: event input$goBu ...")
    req(defcat != input$selectCAT, dat_mt(), dat_ir())
    mt <- dat_mt()
    ir <- dat_ir()
    # WARNING: potential for SQL injection, proof-of-concept only
    out <- sqldf(paste("select * from mt where cyl =", input$selectCAT))
    msg("Out: event input$goBu ...")
    out
  })

  output$acBTTON <- renderTable({
    msg("In: acBTTN ...")
    req(pf())
    out <- pf()
    msg("Out: acBTTN ...")
    out
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

The second, with dynamic UI. The only two differences are noted:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file1", "Import", accept = ".xlsx"),
    ## replace selectInput with this:
    uiOutput("selectCATdyn"),
    ## end dif
    actionButton("goBu", "Click!")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    "Display Results",
    tableOutput("acBTTON")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat_mt <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    msg("In: dat_mt ...")
    req(input$file1)
    out <- readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath, "mt")
    msg("Out: dat_mt ...")
    out
  })
  dat_ir <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    msg("In: dat_ir ...")
    req(input$file1)
    out <- readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath, "ir")
    msg("Out: dat_ir ...")
    out
  })

  ## replace observeEvent(dat_mt(),... with      
  output$selectCATdyn <- renderUI({
    req(dat_mt(), dat_ir())
    selectInput(inputId = "selectCAT", label = "Selection",
                choices = c(defcat, sort(unique(dat_mt()$cyl))),
                selected = defcat)
  })
  ## end diff

  pf <- eventReactive(input$goBu, {
    msg("In: event input$goBu ...")
    on.exit( msg("Out: event input$goBu ...") )
    req(defcat != input$selectCAT, dat_mt(), dat_ir())
    mt <- dat_mt()
    ir <- dat_ir()
    # WARNING: potential for SQL injection, proof-of-concept only
    out <- sqldf(paste("select * from mt where cyl =", input$selectCAT))
    out
  })

  output$acBTTON <- renderTable({
    msg("In: acBTTN ...")
    req(pf())
    out <- pf()
    msg("Out: acBTTN ...")
    out
  })
}
```

As I play with this, I realize why you wanted dynamic UI, so it now "makes more sense" :-)

Side note, though: you can have a similar effect by defining it statically (as in my first solution) and use `shinyjs::hide` or `shinyjs::disable` inside another `observe` block.

---

Setup:

```
wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, "mt")
openxlsx::writeDataTable(wb, "mt", x = mtcars)
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, "ir")
openxlsx::writeDataTable(wb, "ir", x = iris)
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, "Johnseito.xlsx")
```

Comment: Looks very nice, I like what you did.                                                                                               
The only thing is I have a file that has 19 tabs and I need to create 19 data frames. Wonder if there is an easier way to do it otherwise I have to create one eventReactive for each ?  seems like R is not big on loops, and while data frame can have a great number of fields, I think over 10k, using sqldf or dbGetQuery is limited to only 999 columns.

Comment: *"seems like R is not big on loops"* is perhaps a little mis-placed ... it used to be the case that `for` loops were "vastly" (subjective) less efficient than other methods, but that was addressed and "fixed" years ago. R shies away from it because it does vectorized stuff very well, so there is often a better way to do things. So, with 19 tabs, I would likely reduce the two `dat_*` blocks to a single block that iterates over sheets, something like `lapply(excel_sheets(...$datapath), function(s) read_excel(...$datapath, sheet=s))`.

Comment: `dbGetQuery` is limited to 999 columns? I've never tried ... I'd think that table structure would be ... rather horrid ... is there a particular reason you need to stick with `sqldf`? I'd think `dplyr` or `data.table` would suffice, since you need to load things into memory anyway. Just a thought, no big push away from it, I know SQL can sometimes be more comfortable.

Comment: "is there a particular reason you need to stick with sqldf?" Because sqldf is easier to reshape/ bend data, at least for me. I am not that familiar with dplyr or data.table. And the other reason is because I want to join the 19 data frame together and use it to do filters when user select certain items, etc. I found out how to use for loop to create multiple data frame, but wasn't sure the lapply way as I am still looking.

Comment: Johnseito, if this answers your question, please "accept" it.