# Error generated while running the shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Edit: Can anybody tell me how to add random forest model in shiny.

```
    library(shiny)

    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)

ntshiny <- read.csv("NT4.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Random Forest Model prediction of impact of Tickets raised"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("SpecificsOutput"),
      uiOutput("ComponentOutput"),
      uiOutput("CategoryOutput")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("coolplot"),
      br(),
      br(),
      tableOutput("results")
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$SpecificsOutput <- renderUI({
      selectInput("SpecificsInput", "Specifics",
                  sort(unique(ntshiny$Specifics)),
                  selected = "Fault Management")
    })
    output$ComponentOutput <- renderUI({
      selectInput("ComponentInput", "Component",
                  sort(unique(ntshiny$Component)),
                  selected = "Admin Event") 
    })
    output$CategoryOutput <- renderUI({
      selectInput("CategoryInput", "Category",
                  sort(unique(ntshiny$Category)),
                  selected = "Security")
    })

    filtered <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$SpecificsInput)) {
        return(NULL)
      }
      if (is.null(input$ComponentInput)) {
        return(NULL)
      }
      if (is.null(input$CategoryInput)) {
        return(NULL)
      }

    ntshiny %>%
      filter(
        Specifics == input$SpecificsInput,
        Component == input$ComponentInput,
        Category == input$Category
      )
    })

    output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
      if (is.null(filtered())) {
        return()
      }
      ggplot(filtered(), aes(Impact)) +
        geom_histogram()
    })

    output$results <- renderTable({
      filtered()
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I build random forest model for predicting the impact of tickets. Now I am trying to build the shiny app for predicting the impact. So in the shiny script I am uploading my file. But when I run the app it says

```
Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable 68: levels
```

I don't know whats going on with this code.
Please help me here. Thank you very much.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
shinyUI( pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel( "Random Forest model applied to network tickets dataset"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file_input", "Upload your dataset"),
    h4("Ticket's attributes:"),
    br(),
    selectInput( "cl", "Specifics", levels(df[1,6]), "Fault Management"),
    selectInput( "se", "Component", levels(df[1,5]), "Admin Event"),
    selectInput( "ag", "Category", levels(df[1,2]), "Security"),
    br(),
    h4("Random Forest prediction:"),
    br(),
    h5("Impact ?"),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h3("Network Ticket data set"),
    p("It provides information about the ticket raised"),
    h3("Random Forest prediction"),
    p("Based on this data set this ShinyApp uses a Random Forest prediction model and display the associated stats numbers based on ticket's attributes"),
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
))


mdata <- read_csv(input$file_input$datapath)
mod <- randomForest(Survived ~ .data = mdata)

shinyServer( function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    selectedData <- df[df$Specifics==input$cl & df$Component==input$se & df$Category==input$ag,5]
    bplt <- barplot(selectedData,
                    beside=TRUE, horiz=TRUE, xlim=c(0,50),
                    main="Impact stats based on selected tickets attributes",
                    ylab="Total",
                    col=c("black", "grey"),
                    legend = c("Service Impacting", "Non-Service Impacting")
    )
    text(x=selectedData+20,
         y=bplt,
         labels=as.character(selectedData),
         xpd=TRUE)
  })
  output$result <- renderText({ 
    r <- predict(mod, df[df$Specifics==input$cl & df$Component==input$se & df$Category==input$ag & df$Impact=="Yes",1:1])
    levels(r)[r]
  })
})
```

Comment: Errors about `closure` are typically because you are including a `function` (or `call` or related) where *data* is expected. Since `df` is also a base function, it seems likely that you do not have data defined into `df` as you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I understand now what was wrong. I have a quick question about shiny app .I am first uploading the dataset in shiny app. So my question is how do I need to call the variables. So in the above code (selectInput( "cl", "Specifics", levels(df[1,6]), "Fault Management"),) what do I need to use? Hope I explained it well.

Comment: You cannot reference `df` in the `ui` portion of a shiny app. Look into `updateSelectInput`, a call that should like go in an `observe` or `observeEvent` block within the `server` component, reacting to the data that is actually uploaded by the user. (You can also use `uiOutput` and `renderUI`, though I think I prefer the `update*` method.)

Comment: Another thing: `input$file_input` is only available inside of the server component, you cannot do what you want. The [help page for `fileInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/fileInput.html) has a small example, and the [gallery example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html) has another. Both are rather terse, but have a try at those and then come back and update your question if you still are unsure.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to shiny.that is why the confusions. I would really appreciate if you can make the change in my code so that I can learn further on that topic.

Comment: ok I will try them now.

Comment: Hey @r2evans, I went through those examples. I was able to get the table into the UI. I am trying to get inputs from user and then predict something based on a RF model. I am not able to take those values - run the model - show the prediction... I am having a hard time getting those value from FE to BE...

Comment: It might help to look at other examples that use `fileInput` in various ways: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53246394/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050728/3358272 are the most recent I've dealt with.

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help. I was finally able to write a new code and it is running fine. I have a quick question: How can I write a random forest model inside the server function. I want to predict impact based on the three variables Soecifics, Category and Component.

Comment: *Completely* different question ... and likely much simpler than you think. How do you run it in the console? It might be useful to look at the [*Retirement Simulator*](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/retirement-simulation.html) (found in the [shiny gallery](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/)). It might be a little complex, but it demonstrates (1) separating "running" the model and storing it from (2) plotting results from the model. Depending on the runtime, you might benefit from searching for "long running shiny apps" for things like `async` to try to mitigate delays.